# Correct async function export in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I had my custom module with following code:

```
module.exports.PrintNearestStore = async function PrintNearestStore(session, lat, lon) {
...
}
```

It worked fine if call the function outside my module, however if I called inside I got error while running:

> (node:24372) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
>   rejection (rejection id: 1): ReferenceError: PrintNearestStore is not
>   defined

When I changed syntax to:

```
module.exports.PrintNearestStore = PrintNearestStore;

var PrintNearestStore = async function(session, lat, lon) {

}
```

It started to work fine inside module, but fails outside the module - I got error:

> (node:32422) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
>   rejection (rejection id: 1): TypeError: mymodule.PrintNearestStore is
>   not a function

So I've changed code to:

```
module.exports.PrintNearestStore = async function(session, lat, lon) {
    await PrintNearestStore(session, lat, lon);
}

var PrintNearestStore = async function(session, lat, lon) {
...
}
```

And now it works in all cases: inside and outside. However want to understand semantics and if there is more beautiful and shorter way to write it? How to correctly  define and use **async** function both: inside and outside (exports) module?

Answer (score 135, accepted):

This doesn't really have anything to with async functions specially. If you want to call a function internally *and* export it, define it *first* and then export it.

```
async function doStuff() {
  // ...
}
// doStuff is defined inside the module so we can call it wherever we want

// Export it to make it available outside
module.exports.doStuff = doStuff;
```

---

Explanation of the problems with your attempts:

```
module.exports.PrintNearestStore = async function PrintNearestStore(session, lat, lon) {
...
}
```

This does not define a function in the module. The function definition is a function *expression*. The name of a function expression only creates a variable inside the function itself. Simpler example:

```js
var foo = function bar() {
  console.log(typeof bar); // 'function' - works
};
foo();
console.log(typeof foo); // 'function' - works
console.log(typeof bar); // 'undefined' - there is no such variable `bar`
```

See also [Named function expressions demystified](https://kangax.github.io/nfe/). You could of course refer to the function if you'd refer to `module.exports.PrintNearestStore` everywhere.

---

```
module.exports.PrintNearestStore = PrintNearestStore;

var PrintNearestStore = async function(session, lat, lon) {

}
```

This is *almost* OK. The problem is that the value of `PrintNearestStore` is `undefined` when you assign it to `module.exports.PrintNearestStore`. The order of execution is:

```
var PrintNearestStore; // `undefined` by default
// still `undefined`, hence `module.exports.PrintNearestStore` is `undefined`
module.exports.PrintNearestStore = PrintNearestStore;

PrintNearestStore = async function(session, lat, lon) {}
// now has a function as value, but it's too late
```

Simpler example:

```js
var foo = bar;
console.log(foo, bar); // logs `undefined`, `undefined` because `bar` is `undefined`
var bar = 21;
console.log(foo, bar); // logs `undefined`, `21`
```

If you changed the order it would work as expected.

---

```
module.exports.PrintNearestStore = async function(session, lat, lon) {
    await PrintNearestStore(session, lat, lon);
}

var PrintNearestStore = async function(session, lat, lon) {
...
}
```

This works because *by the time* the function assigned to `module.exports.PrintNearestStore` *is executed*, `PrintNearestStore` has the function as its value.

Simpler example:

```js
var foo = function() {
  console.log(bar);
};
foo(); // logs `undefined`
var bar = 21;
foo(); // logs `21`
```

Comment: Thank You, I see. Just reordered function definition (removed `var`) and `module.exports` now - function definition first. I see that for Internal call function definition order is not important: I have function call BEFORE its definition, however for `module.exports` it matters.

Comment: @AlekseyKontsevich: FWIW, Line A being *before* line B in the source code doesn't mean that line A is *executed* *before* line B. In the end, the order of execution is the only thing that matters. Of course the function definition has to be evaluated before the function can be called. However, the order of execution might not be obvious in JS due to hoisting.

Answer (score 9):

an alternative would be to export like this.
// foo.js

```js
export async function foo(){ 
 console.log('I am greatest of all.'); // for the person who reads it, just say it.
}
```

then use it in other scripts like

```js
import { foo } from './foo'

foo();
```

Answer (score 5):

Error with first case: `PrintNearestStore` - Function expression, so this name not available outside.

error with second case: using variable, instead Function declaration. In this case, declaration of variable PrintNearestStore are hoisted, so, you can use this name *before* line `var PrintNearestStore = ...`, but in this case value would be *undefined*.

So, simplest solution change second variant like this:

```
module.exports.PrintNearestStore = PrintNearestStore;

async function PrintNearestStore(session, lat, lon) {

}
```

Comment: Won't work: need to put function definition first, then `module.exports`.

Comment: As I said above I got `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning` for such code in node 8.6. I put function definition first then `module.exports` to fix.

Comment: @AlekseyKontsevich, for detecting error in your case, we should have [mcve], like me provide above

Comment: Do not worry, all is solved already: see answer above. You may delete Yours one.

Comment: @AlekseyKontsevich due to hoisting, it does not matter where you put the function.

Answer (score 2):

Some examples:

```
module.exports.func1 = async function func1(id) {  // name is preferred by linter
  //
};

module.exports.func1 = async function (id) { // ok
  //
};

module.exports.func1 = async (id) => { // simpler
  //
};
```

Answer (score 2):

```
export let handlePostStore = async (data) => {
    console.log('post');
    return data;
};

// to import 
import { handlePostStore } from 'your_path_here';

// to call it 
handlePostStore(data)
```

Comment: Code dumps do not make for good answers. You should explain how and why this solves their problem. I recommend reading, [How do I write a good answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7656/how-do-i-write-a-good-answer-to-a-question)

Comment: I got error 

> export let handlePostStore = async (data) => {
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'