# Why is this function definition ignored?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

Can anyone figure out why I get

```
TypeError: getStatusCode(...) is not a function
```

when I do?

```
const getStatusCode = require('./getStatusCode')
tmpStatus = await getStatusCode({url: url, timeOut: to, maxRedirects: mr})
(tmpStatus === alert['Check']['Status_code'] ) ? isOk = 1 : isOk = 0
```

The problem goes any if I remove the last line, where I check the value in `tmpStatus`.

**getStatusCode.js**

```
const axios = require('axios')
const qs = require('qs')

module.exports = async function(options) => {
  options              = options || {}
  options.url          = options.url || {}
  options.string       = options.string || null
  options.timeOut      = options.timeOut || 1000
  options.maxRedirects = options.maxRedirects || 0

  try {
    const response = await axios.get(options.url, {
      timeout: options.timeout,
      maxRedirects: options.maxRedirects,
      validateStatus: null,
      transformResponse: [function (data) {
        return data.search(options.string)
  }],
    })
    return await response.data
  } catch (error) {
    return -1
  }
}
```

Comment: What does `console.log(typeof getStatusCode)` show?

Comment: When I run that code it throws `SyntaxError: Unexpected token '=>'`

Comment: `async function(options) =>` doesn't make sense - which kind of function are you writing?

Comment: And when I fix that error, it runs fine. I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Barmar It returns `function`...

Comment: Does it really have `(...)` in the error message? That would happen if you added another set of parentheses: `getStatusCode({url: url, timeOut: to, maxRedirects: mr})()`

Comment: @Barmar And then it writes `TypeError: console.log(...) is not a function`. All I did were inserting your line.

Comment: Again, that would only happen if you wrote `console.log(typeof getStatusCode)()`

Comment: If that's not what you're writing, something else is manipulating your input and adding extra function calls.

Comment: If the problem were with `getStatusCode` itself it would just say `getStatusCode is not a function`, without the `(...)`

Comment: Take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46715585/217867) and the question above it.

Comment: @Barmar After some debugging. It is this line that creates the issue `(tmpStatus === alert['Check']['Status_code'] ) ? isOk = 1 : isOk = 0`, and gives the fault to the line above. What is going on here?

Comment: Re edit: This is now a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846283/what-are-the-rules-for-javascripts-automatic-semicolon-insertion-asi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is because you didn't put a `;` at the end of the assignment line. So it's being interpreted as if you wrote

```
tmpStatus = await getStatusCode({url: url, timeOut: to, maxRedirects: mr})(tmpStatus === alert['Check']['Status_code'] ) 
    ? isOk = 1 : isOk = 0;
```

This is trying to use the result of `getStatusCode()` as a function, with the value of `tmpStatus === alert['Check']['Status_code']` as its argument.

See [What are the rules for JavaScript's automatic semicolon insertion (ASI)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846283/what-are-the-rules-for-javascripts-automatic-semicolon-insertion-asi)

I recommend you always use semicolons, rather than depending on ASI.

Comment: I had no idea that a function could return a function! When I Google `nodejs return function from function` I don't get anything meaningful. Can you give me a link where I can read about this?

Comment: https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-functions I found many answers by googling `javascript function returning function`

Comment: `require()` is a function, and it's returning a function when you do `getStatusCode = require(...)`. So how could you be unaware that a function can return a function?

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the `=>`.

```
const axios = require('axios')
const qs = require('qs')

module.exports = async function(options) {
  options              = options || {}
  options.url          = options.url || {}
  options.string       = options.string || null
  options.timeOut      = options.timeOut || 1000
  options.maxRedirects = options.maxRedirects || 0

  try {
    const response = await axios.get(options.url, {
      timeout: options.timeout,
      maxRedirects: options.maxRedirects,
      validateStatus: null,
      transformResponse: [function (data) {
        return data.search(options.string)
  }],
    })
    return await response.data
  } catch (error) {
    return -1
  }
}
```

Comment: I still get the same error.

Comment: did you restart the server before running?